# Can not reproduce this [ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

This one has me stumped.  Three of my clients have received this error, but I can not reproduce it on my end!

> [Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

**In general**, what would cause a discrepancy in who receives this kind of DB error, what kind of issues would keep me from being able to replicate it on my end?

Here's the bit of code that I believe is causing the error:

```
<cfquery 
name="rsAddSKUs" 
datasource="#request.dsn#" 
username="#request.dsnUsername#" 
password="#request.dsnPassword#">
    INSERT INTO 
    tbl_orderskus 
        ( orderSKU_OrderID
        , orderSKU_SKU
        , orderSKU_Quantity
        , orderSKU_UnitPrice
        , orderSKU_SKUTotal
        , orderSKU_Picked
        , orderSKU_TaxRate
        , orderSKU_DiscountID
        , orderSKU_DiscountAmount)
    VALUES 
        ('#var.ThisOrderID#'
        , #rsGetCart.SKU_ID#
        , #rsGetCart.Qty#
        , #rsGetCart.SKU_Price#
        , #SKUTotal#
        , 0
        , #var.thisProductTax#
        , #var.thisDiscountID#
        , #var.thisdiscountAmount#)
</cfquery>
```

Thanks,
Biscotti

Comment: As an aside, you should be using `cfqueryparam`. It is never a good idea to use raw client values directly within sql - even with MS Access.

Comment: @Leigh Great tip. Im actually working on migrating the site over to mySQL for scalability reasons. Is there any downside to coding using cfqueryparam, or a better way to handle sql injection in mySQL?

Comment: Nothing is completely without quirks, but for basic cfquery protection, cfqueryparam is the best option. Plus it has a lot of other benefits like type checking, list handling, promoting query plan resuse (helps performance). Those are the primary reasons to use it. Basic sql injection protection is just a bonus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first inclination is one of the numeric fields are blank and the insert statement is trying to insert a ,, instead of a value

Comment: I think you are correct, it looks like Im setting <cfparam name="var.thisDiscountID" default="">   The DB is expecting a number in that collumn

Comment: You need to add some conditional logic so that if the value is not a number, insert null into that column.

Comment: Either `null` OR a default number (if appropriate). Just so there is *some* value in between the two commas. Otherwise, it is not a valid sql statement.

Answer (score 4):

Can you log the "Insert" command to a logfile and then get your clients to get them to send you the logfile to see what the offending insert command is?

I was thinking if the insert command depends on user input then they could be inputting something strange.

Comment: your point is well taken.  It was not until this error that I implemented cferror to inform me of the kinds of error that are happening behind my back!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your numeric values in [`val()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e64.html) so that you get 0 instead of an empty string.